# Can you run a VB application in full-screen?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, fullscreen

I just want to ask:
How do you get an application, using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 express, to run in full screen mode. You know what I mean, like a game would but an application.

Is it possible? If not, tell me how and what I need to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating a Windows Forms application or a WPF application?

Comment: I'm creating a Windows Forms application, sorry I should of said that. Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your Form_load add the following two lines:

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Obviously, you can place the code elsewhere than in form_load - and depending on your list of includes you may need more or less prepending.

Answer (score 3):

set the `WindowState` property to `Maximized`

Comment: sorry, my bad. set the 'FormBorderStyle' to 'None'

Answer (score 2):

The `FormBorderStyle` line is essential to show as full screen, so the top bar controls are not visible.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

Comment: This is identical to [user806549's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658048/812786).